# neo4j windows desktop: Unrecoverable authentication error

Tags: neo4j

I run `ne04j-desktop-1.0.6-setup.exe` to install the desktop neo4j application, and it proceeds through the install up to the point where it opens, and then gives the message (in a red warning rectangle with only a dismiss button) "Unrecoverable authentication error".

How can I find out what the error is and try to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, try to put the comptability mode on Windows 7. If it don't work immediatly, try to reload the app by clicking on "Reload" in the "Developper" tab.