# Neo4j Windows Desktop v.1.0.6 install won't create new database, error: invalid central directory file header signature

Tags: neo4j, installation

I have downloaded and attempted to install the 1.0.6 version of the Neo4j Desktop (Graph Platform) under Windows 10. The silent installation happens quickly without any prompting about where to install or what to expect installation-wise. Upon installation the Neo4j Desktop icon is added to the Windows desktop and the Desktop automatically opens with the appearance that it is all ready to go.

I select the default MyProject and click the New Database panel. The Local/Remote dialog pops up, I select Local. I accept the default Database name, don't add an optional description and click the Create button at which time I a red error dialog pops up saying:

```
`Database failed to create: Error: invalid central directory file header signature: 0xef42a50`
```

I get this result whether I create a new project and then attempt to create a new database in that new project. I get the same result if I change default names of proposed new databases. I can't attach to a remote new database because Neo4j does not appear to be running at this point and I have been given no indication where the installation even put anything.

When I ferret out the installation, I find it has silently been put in the typically hidden user subdirectories of "../AppData/Local/Programs/neo4j-desktop" and "..AppData/Roaming/Neo4j Desktop".

In the Roaming neo4j subdirectory, I find the log.log file which contains the single line of warning `[2017-11-28 16:42:30:0451] [warn] auth is not initialised yet`.

Any insights/recommendations appreciated. I am a "retired" #CitizenScientist and around most of the time to answer additional questions or to try any recommended fixes.

BTW, I have been using Neo4j Community Edition on my Windows dev box for years, mostly the manually installed version that provides support for running as a Windows service.

Also, my issue seems similar to this installation failure cited here: [neo4j windows desktop: Unrecoverable authentication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540422/neo4j-windows-desktop-unrecoverable-authentication-error).